# GroupBox' offset in SplitView

Tags: qt, user-interface, qml, qtquick2

With the following `QML` code:

```
    SplitView {
        orientation: Qt.Vertical

        anchors.fill: parent

        GroupBox {
//            id: inputBox
            title: "First"
            Layout.fillWidth: true

            anchors.top: parent.top

            anchors.topMargin: UI.boxMargin
            anchors.bottomMargin: UI.boxMargin
        }

        GroupBox {
            title: "Second"
            Layout.fillWidth: true

//            x: 15

//            anchors.topMargin: 15//UI.boxMargin
//            anchors.bottomMargin: UI.boxMargin
        }
    }
```

I have achieved the following design:[image]

The splitter is composed of two lines: a darker and one of the lighters. I want to add some offset between the splitter and the second `GroupBox` to avoid the (ugly) superposition, but I did not succeed until now (the commented code is useless).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add [`Layout.topMargin`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-layout.html#topMargin-attached-prop) to the second `GroupBox`. For example,

```
SplitView {
    orientation: Qt.Vertical
    anchors.fill: parent

    GroupBox {
        title: "First"
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        height: 80
    }
    GroupBox {
        title: "Second"
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        Layout.topMargin: 15
    }
}
```